# Modbus read and write value conflict

Tags: c#, multithreading, modbus, critical-section

My colleague and I working on project, where some physical devices are connected to Modbus interface(e.g. Lamp), and an desktop app where we sending requests to modbus using NModbus package, and also from time to time(e.g. after every 1 second) reading data from Modbus. We have a classic read/write conflict. Reading has no issue, but sometimes when we writing new value to modbus, the physical lamp going crazy and changing his state every 1 second.

Reading data from modbus is in different task, so do writing new values to modbus.

What we`ve tried:

- lock critical section(only writing), and ignoring reading data when new value comes. After that we have a problem with queue and very slow working
- CancellationToken - had no effect, or I writing it bad

Currently we have a class that collects property date of last state change(registered in IoC) and when new writing value comes, then we updating this property, and blocking from reading data from Modbus. Unfortunately this code sometimes working, sometimes not.

Please help. We are going crazy with this issue and we don`t know how to fix it.

Edit: I posting current code.

This is task, where we executing GetCurrentState handler

```
    public void Start()
{
    var cancellationToken = _cancellationTokenSource.Token;

    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(ReadStateDelayInMiliseconds).ConfigureAwait(false);

            if ((DateTime.Now - _lastCommandExecutionTimeContainer.LastCommandExecutionTime).TotalMilliseconds < _userCommandThresholdInMiliseconds)
                continue;

            try
            {
                await _service.GetCurrentState().ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Error($"Error while checking current state. Message '{ex.Message}', Stack trace: '{ex.StackTrace}'.");
            }

        }
    }, cancellationToken);
}
```

This is GetCurrentState handler, where we reading data from Modbus

```
    protected override IgnisLightState Handle(GetState request)
{
    if ((DateTime.Now - _lastCommandExecutionTimeContainer.LastCommandExecutionTime).TotalMilliseconds <= _configuration.UserCommandThresholdInMiliseconds)
    {
        Logger.Debug($"Ignore before read state from lights, time after last execution: '{(DateTime.Now - _lastCommandExecutionTimeContainer.LastCommandExecutionTime).TotalMilliseconds}'.");
        return _state;
    }

    var currentLightState = _state.DeepClone();

    foreach (var head in currentLightState.Heads)
    {
        try
        {
            ushort startAddress = 0x0000;
            ushort numberOfPointsToRead = 0x0006;

            var values = _modbusMaster.ReadHoldingRegisters((byte)head.UniqueId, startAddress, numberOfPointsToRead);

            var isOn = values[IgnisRegistry.On.Value];
            var isEndo = values[IgnisRegistry.Endo.Value];
            var isCentrum = values[IgnisRegistry.Centrum.Value];
            var tempValue = values[IgnisRegistry.Temp.Value];
            var illuminanceValue = values[IgnisRegistry.Vol.Value];

            head.ColorValue = Convert.ToInt32(tempValue);
            head.IlluminanceValue = Convert.ToInt32(illuminanceValue);
            head.IsCentrumOn = Convert.ToBoolean(isCentrum);
            head.IsEndoOn = Convert.ToBoolean(isEndo);
            head.IsTurnedOn = Convert.ToBoolean(isOn);

            if (currentLightState.CameraState != null &&
                _configuration.CameraHeadId.HasValue &&
                _configuration.CameraHeadId.Value == head.UniqueId)
            {
                var camMode = values[IgnisRegistry.Cam.Value];

                currentLightState.CameraState.IsTurnedOn = Convert.ToBoolean(isOn);
                currentLightState.CameraState.CurrentMode = (IgnisCameraMode)Convert.ToInt32(camMode);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.ErrorFixed(ex, $"Error while getting data from headId {head.UniqueId}.");
        }
    }

    if (_state.Equals(currentLightState)
        || (DateTime.Now - _lastCommandExecutionTimeContainer.LastCommandExecutionTime).TotalMilliseconds < _configuration.UserCommandThresholdInMiliseconds)
    {
        Logger.Debug($"Ignore after read state from lights, time after last execution: '{(DateTime.Now - _lastCommandExecutionTimeContainer.LastCommandExecutionTime).TotalMilliseconds}'.");
        return _state;
    }

    foreach (var currentHeadState in currentLightState.Heads)
    {
        _lightHeadStateUpdater.UpdateState(currentHeadState);
    }

    Logger.Debug($"Broadcast new state to clients '{JsonConvert.SerializeObject(currentLightState)}'.");
    _hubContext.Clients.All.StateChanged(currentLightState);

    return currentLightState;
}
```

This is an Turn on lamp handler where we writing new value to modbus:

```
    protected override Response Handle(TurnOn request)
{
    _lastCommandExecutionTimeContainer.SetLastCommandExecutionTime(DateTime.Now);

    if (request.HeadId <= 0
        || !_state.Heads.Any(x=>x.UniqueId == request.HeadId))
    {
        return ResponseFactory.FromError(Error.NotExist);
    }

    var headState = _state.Heads.Single(x=>x.UniqueId == request.HeadId);

    if (headState.IsTurnedOn)
        return ResponseFactory.FromError(Error.AlreadyAsRequested);

    _modbusMaster.WriteSingleRegister((byte)request.HeadId, IgnisRegistry.On.Value, 0x0001);
    headState.IsTurnedOn = true;

    if (_state.CameraState != null &&
        _ignisLightConfiguration.CameraHeadId.HasValue &&
        _ignisLightConfiguration.CameraHeadId.Value == request.HeadId)
    {
        _state.CameraState.IsTurnedOn = true;
    }


    Logger.Trace($"Turn head lamp {request.HeadId} on.");
    _hubContext.Clients.All.HeadStateChanged(headState);

    return ResponseFactory.Success;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should show the relevant parts of your code to get proper help.

Comment: Ok, i will try.